# How to install the OpenCensus extension with PECL on PHP

Tags: php, pecl, opencensus

Following the instructions (here: https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-php) I am unable to install the OpenCensus extension for PHP using PECL.

I have tried installing other PECL extensions, which worked fine.

I have also tried doing this from a VPN.

The install steps I tried are:

---

1. Install the opencensus/opencensus package using composer:

```
$ composer require opencensus/opencensus:~0.2
IMPORTANT: Please ensure your version is >= 0.2.0. There is a potential security vulnerability in < 0.2.0.
```

2. Install the opencensus extension from PECL:

```
$ pecl install opencensus-alpha
```

---

The error I get is:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/opencensus" install failed"

See also: https://prnt.sc/nnt5er